# How to add new columns to an Excel file in my local system using Vanilla Javascript?

Tags: javascript, excel

I am getting a `JSON` back from an API and want to add this data as a new column to an Excel file that already has some data. I wanted to ask that is this possible using just frontend Javascript (without involving Node.js)? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it using the library exceljs

Github: https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs

NPM: https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs

CDN: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/exceljs@1.13.0/dist/exceljs.min.js

```
<input type="file" onchange="parseChoosenExcelFile(this)">

function parseChoosenExcelFile(inputElement) {
    var files = inputElement.files || [];
    if (!files.length) return;
    var file = files[0];

    console.time();
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(event) {
    var arrayBuffer = reader.result;
    // var buffer = Buffer.from(arrayBuffer)
    // debugger

    var workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
    // workbook.xlsx.read(buffer)
    workbook.xlsx.load(arrayBuffer).then(function(workbook) {
       console.timeEnd();
       var result = ''
       workbook.worksheets.forEach(function (sheet) {
          sheet.eachRow(function (row, rowNumber) {
             result += row.values + ' | \n'
          })
       })
       // Output somewhere your result file
       // result2.innerHTML = result
       });
     };
   reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}
```

Comment: How do I add ```require``` to the script section in my html file?

Comment: Yep, I rewrote the code and also attached links to CDN JS for the script you need to link to your HTML.